# Spring spel in open projection

Tags: spring-data-jpa, projection, spring-el

My goal is to combine map from some spring data projection.
Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
// id, getters and boilerplate

private List<Child> childs
}
```

and projection be like:

```
interface ParentProjection{
@Value("target.childs == null ? null : {target.childs![name]: target.childs![id'})
Map<String,Long> getChildNameAndId();
}
```

It compiles but when it reaches getChildAndId() in application it falls with :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Projection type must be an interface!

Answer (score 1):

You can search Stackoverflow, there are similar questions with answers that might help you:
["java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Projection type must be an interface" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825928/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-projection-type-must-be-an-interface-error)

[Spring JPA - "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Projection type must be an interface!" (using native query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247358/spring-jpa-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-projection-type-must-be-an-int)

Comment: I ve checked these treads before and after your comment. They didn't clear the problem, though.

Comment: Still relevant.